# Is there a way to concat strings/bytes at compile time?

Tags: rust, constants

Consider this example:

```rs
const TARGET_DIRECTORY: &'static str = "files";
const INDEX_FILE_PATH: &'static str = TARGET_DIRECTORY + "/index.txt"; // Should resolve to "files/index.txt"
```

This falters since the string on the left (`TARGET_DIRECTORY`) needs to be a `String` in order to use the `+` operator. One might try invoking `TARGET_DIRECTORY.to_owned()`, but that can't be executed at compilation.

Comment: As a remark: be aware that `/` is an OS-dependent separator. Correct would be [`std::path::MAIN_SEPARATOR`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/path/constant.MAIN_SEPARATOR.html), which can of course be used with the concatenation methods as mentioned in your answer.

Comment: I thought Rust handles it? I'm running this on Windows where the delimiter is "\", but the code works fine with `/`.

Comment: Most Rust functions are built with some resilience, but it's still advised to use a proper separator for the given platform. Ideally one would not use `String`/`&str` for this at all, but instead use `Path`/`PathBuf`. `Path::push()` adds the proper separator automatically, but of course this is not `const` compatible. That's at least my understanding, I might be wrong.

Comment: @tigerros Rust doesn't silently change the separator in a string, but Windows also accepts "/" in most (all?) circumstances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the [constcat](https://crates.io/crates/constcat) crate right after posting. There's other ones but this one is the simplest and smallest one. I'll mark this as an answer in 2 days.